# SQL get sum of multiple averages

Tags: sql, sum, inner-join, average

I have a table with Songs, users and users rating of the song.

**ratings.***

| userID | songID | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 95 | 1 | 8 |
| 12 | 1 | 6 |
| 95 | 1 | 8 |
| 13 | 1 | 6 |
| 81 | 2 | 3 |
| 42 | 2 | 1 |
| 51 | 3 | 6 |
| 22 | 3 | 6 |

I also have a table thet matches songID's and artists.

**songs.***

| songID | artist |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Michal Jackson |
| 2 | Queen |

What I need is to get the average rating of each song, and then take the sum to find a total rating for the artist.

So here, ill try to show with the input, Michel Jackson.

```
SELECT SUM( AVG(ratings.rating WHERE songID=1) + AVG(ratings.rating WHERE songID=3) )
```

**Wanted output**

| Input, artist | Output, total rating |
| --- | --- |
| "Michal Jackson" | 13 |
| "Queen" | 2 |

Every answer is really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I don't know what happened to the formatting. It looks fine in the preview, but awful on the main page. EDIT: its fixed now

Comment: Are you sure that your AVG() + AVG() formula is correct?

Comment: No, its probably not, its just to illustrate what the output need to be like.

Comment: I bet you are looking to AVG() each song by artist and then take an overall average of all songs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its almost how I intended it, but I need the overall SUM, not AVG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a **derived table** (using a subquery as a table):

```sql
SELECT
    songID
    , SUM(average_rating) AS total_rating
FROM (
        SELECT
            songID
            , artist
            , AVG(rating) AS average_rating
        FROM songs
        GROUP BY songID
    ) AS song_ratings
GROUP BY artist
```

Comment: The rating in my case is stars, so I want to be able to calculate the total stars for each artist.

Comment: Ok, if it has a meaning to you then that's it, I'm deleting this sentence from my answer :-) Feel free to ask any question if my answer is not clear enough to you.

Comment: Thank you, you're a real life saver.

Comment: You can upvote and accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Yes, just need to test it first. I will of course check it as solved once verified!